# Query image from SalesForce as blob

Tags: javascript, rest, salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud

Is there any way I can query the image from SalesForce server as a blob object ?
We already have forcetk client queries which is retrieving all the data, but the image alone is returned as a link (salesforce link).

Can we retrieve image as blob in the same REST query call ?

The methods I saw required to make an extra call to fetch images, but here I have images in each row of the result, it would have been better if images come as a part of result object itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the REST API, then the blob data can't be returned with the rest of the object, it has to be a separate request. If you use SOAP then it can inline the blob data with the rest of the fields for the object, but it will be limited to returning one row at a time.